# How can I retrieve information on failed LogicApps runs that aren't available in AppInsights and Log Analytics workspace?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I'm currently trying to retrieve information on failed LogicApps runs, trying to find out the reason why the LogicApps failed. I expected to find more in-depth information in Log Analytics based on the Logic Apps diagnostic settings, however it seems the information is not being logged to the AzureDiagnostics table at all.

I would like to relate information why a certain Logic App failed, perhaps even linking it to Application Insights (log analytics). Does someone have an idea how this could be done?

I've looked in to the AzureDiagnostics table (Logic Apps), requests table (Application Insights), ApiManagementGatewayLogs table, however no luck with finding more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You have mainly two ways to retreive logic apps runs logs including and error exceptions:

1. Link LogAnalytics workspace in Diagnostic settings : Then you can query tables like LogicAppWorkflowRuntime, AppRequests, AppExceptions
2. Link your logic apps to Application insights, then you can query tables like traces, requests, exceptions

Comment: Thank you for your response Yassine! Option 1 can display error per action, but not the last action / the actual reason why the Logic App has failed.
Option 2 does only work with Logic Apps Standard, but we use Consumption.